# sql update statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an update sql statement that fails and I don't know the reason..

Is there anything wrong with:

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
if ($req = $db->prepare("UPDATE {$sTable} SET ? = ? WHERE id=?")) {
    $req->bind_param("ssi", $columnName, $value, $id );
    $req->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: of course this is after connecting to the database..

Comment: Make things easier indicating what have you tried, which errors are you getting...

Comment: @fedorqui I'm using ajax to update a "datatables" (http://www.datatables.net/) table but it's not updated..
I don't know why or what is the error..

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind column as string param, your query will look like:

```
UPDATE some_table SET 'column' = 'value' WHERE id=1
```

which is of course wrong. So the answer is you cannot bind column (or table) as parameter in prepared statement.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot..
    <?php
    extract($_POST);
    if ($req = $db->prepare("UPDATE {$sTable} SET {$columnName} = ? WHERE id=?")) {
        $req->bind_param("si", $value, $id );
        $req->execute();
    }
    ?>

Solved the problem..